# How to include component with its separate markup to another markup?

Tags: inheritance, wicket, composition

I have a panel which has defined a place in it where other panel should go. There must not be any inheritance, as not only there is a large number of them but also they are to be used throughout the entire application.

Component that I want to be "included" extends panel itself too. I want to be able to do something like  in component with markup 1, independent from component 2 implementation.

Is it possible to do that? I am perfectly aware of how inheritance works. But there is not much about composition...

The stacktrace:

```
Last cause: The component(s) below failed to render. Possible reasons could be that: 1) you have added a component in code but forgot to reference it in the markup (thus the component will never be rendered), 2) if your components were added in a parent container then make sure the markup for the child container includes them in <wicket:extend>.

1. [BlockingAjaxSubmitLink [Component id = link_language_add]]
2. [ListView [Component id = language_placeholder]]
3. [ListItem [Component id = 0]]
4. [LanguagePanel [Component id = language]]
5. [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = container_name]]
6. [TextField [Component id = name]]
7. [Component id = feedback_name]
8. [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = container_proficiency]]
9. [TextField [Component id = proficiency]]
10. [BlockingAjaxLink [Component id = link_remove]]
11. [ListItem [Component id = 1]]
12. [LanguagePanel [Component id = language]]
13. [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = container_name]]
14. [TextField [Component id = name]]
15. [Component id = feedback_name]
16. [WebMarkupContainer [Component id = container_proficiency]]
17. [TextField [Component id = proficiency]]
18. [BlockingAjaxLink [Component id = link_remove]]
```

All of these components are inside the form or at least should be seen there.

Comment: Can you show some code? I don't understand your problem. You can include panels into panels to your hearts content ..

Comment: Do you mean fragments? This is the way to go? https://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/usingfragments.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay it was pretty stupid mistake I guess.

Just remember the difference between WebMarkupContainer and Panel.

The Panel **HAS** its **own html file** and includes it alongside

whereas

The WebMarkupContainer **DOES NOT HAVE** its **own html file** and relies only on the markup in the file the component is added to.

Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

I see.... well, Try to keep a pattern like this: Page -> Form -> Panel. And also, try to put your components neither in the form or in the panel.

```
public class Page extends WebPage{

private MyForm myForm;

public Page(){
myForm = new()....;
  }

}

public class MyForm extends Form<T>{

  public MyForm(String id){
    super(id);
  }

}

public class MyPanel extends Panel{

//your components

  public MyPanel(String id){
   super(id);
  }

}

[wicket:extend]

  [form wicket:id="myForm"]

    [div wicket:id="myPanel"/]

  [form]
[/wicket:extend]

[wicket:panel]

[div wicket:id="myPanel"]

[/div]

[/wicket:panel]
```

Comment: That's exactly how the structure looked like. Yet what I was missing is the fact, that only Panels can be included with their separate markup to the other one.

Comment: Did you mean,insert a Panel into another Panel's webMarkupContainer? In afirmative case, yes, you can insert it, but not with the same markup_id.